# Save and add another item

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, item

We're using SharePoint online, I've created a custom list, item is save and close per item. Is there such a thing as saving and adding another item (redirecting you to the add item again). Without clicking the add item again.

Comment: please re-phrase your question - it is hard to understand what are you trying to ask

Comment: You can use "quick edit" to add multiple items without refreshing the page

Comment: Unless you need the form for some reason I agree with @GertBraspenning using the quick edit would be the best route.

Comment: Use "quick edit" option to add item in table structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following code to your NewForm.aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('input[value=Save]').click(function() { window.location.replace("http://YOURSITE/Lists/YOURLIST/NewForm.aspx");});
});
</script>
```

It will redirect you to the newform.aspx page each time you save, though. So if you no longer want to add a new item, you have to click cancel. In my opinion, it's probably better to use quick edit (in most situations).